# TextBox BorderBrush is not updating after text is changed

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, textbox, converters

I have WPF TextBox with default BorderBrush. I want to change BorderBrush in red color when TextBox have empty content. Here is my code:

```
<TextBox Width="200" Text="{Binding Path=Description}" Name="tbDescription" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Margin="2" 
                             BorderBrush="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},
                             Path=Text,
                             Converter={StaticResource borderBrushColorConverter}}">
```

And here is my converter:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            string text = value as string;

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
                return Brushes.Red;

            return Brushes.Transparent;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
```

Problem is that border becomes red only when TextBox focus is lost. I tried to use the same code on Background property instead on BorderBrush and then everything works fine.

Comment: The problem is that, by default, WPF adds a blue border around the textbox when it is focused. You should try searching for a way to remove that border. Try this link:  (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6404059/remove-default-mouseover-focus-effect-on-textboxes-in-wpf)

Comment: Does it work if you change your binding mode to `PropertyChanged` instead of the default `LostFocus`?  `Text="{Binding Path=Description, Mode=PropertyChanged}"`

Comment: Don't use a converter here, make a `Style` with a `DataTrigger`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this, style the `Tempalte`:

```
<TextBox BorderBrush="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},
                         Path=Text,
                         Converter={StaticResource borderBrushColorConverter}}">
        <TextBox.Style>
            <Style  TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                            <Border x:Name="Bd" 
                                    SnapsToDevicePixels="true" 
                                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
                                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush }"
                                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" 
                                    Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" 
                                    Height="{TemplateBinding Height}">
                                <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost"></ScrollViewer>
                            </Border>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </TextBox.Style>
    </TextBox>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the problem you're trying to solve is not one of mere conditional styling, but of **data validation**. If that's the case, then it's worth considering adding support for `IDataErrorInfo` or -even better- `INotifyDataErrorInfo` to your view model.

Here follows a possible implementation of the latter on your view model, based on a `Validate` method that gets executed after each property change, and a `Dictionary<string, List<string>>` as per-property error store:

```
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged, INotifyDataErrorInfo
{
    public string Description
    {
        get { return _description; }

        set
        {
            _description = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
            Validate();
        }
    }

    private string _description;

    private void Validate()
    {
        Errors[nameof(Description)].Clear();

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Description))
        {
            Errors[nameof(Description)].Add("The text cannot be empty");
        }

        if (Errors[nameof(Description)].Any())
        {
            NotifyErrorsChanged(nameof(Description));
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable GetErrors(string propertyName)
        => Errors.ContainsKey(propertyName) ? Errors[propertyName] : Enumerable.Empty<string>();

    public bool HasErrors
        => Errors.Any(propertyErrors => (propertyErrors.Value ?? Enumerable.Empty<string>()).Any());

    public event EventHandler<DataErrorsChangedEventArgs> ErrorsChanged;

    protected virtual void NotifyErrorsChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        => ErrorsChanged?.Invoke(this, new DataErrorsChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

    private IDictionary<string, List<string>> Errors { get; }
        = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>
        {
            {nameof(Description), new List<string>()}
        };

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

The view side is reduced to the following:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Description, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```